# ios7 auto layout button resize issue

Tags: ios, iphone, button, layout

I am using xcode 5 with storyboards and autolayout turned ON.  My layouts of one of my ViewControllers has a UIButton with an image background.  The view controller also has 3 buttons anchored to the bottom of the view and some labels above.  I laid out my storyboards to a 4" retina display (ie: iphone 5+) and the issue I have is when simulating to a 3.5" display (ie: iphone 4, 4s, etc)

I have pinned the height of the anchored buttons at the bottom to remain constant.  What I want is when the app runs on a 3.5" display iphone, that the UIButton with the image will resize smaller (keeping all other labels & buttons same size & spacing).  So the aspect ratio would remain the same for that UIButton, it would just get smaller.

I haven't been able to find anything in the auto layout tutorial or others online about how to   set up constraints to do this (where the height/width remain proportional).

Comment: Try clicking on the view in storyboard and then from the icons on the bottom left section from second from right select reset to suggested layouts and see if that will solve your issue. It will automatically add the constrains you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is as follow:
1.Label's top is 100 from its superView and its bottom is 68 from its superView
2.In 4" display, its size is 200x400 with ratio .5
3.In 3.5" display, its size is 312x624 with ratio .5

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // create search bar
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(60, 100, 200, 400);
    _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    _label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_label];

    // layout search bar
    _label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    // height
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_label
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                                     toItem:nil
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                 multiplier:0
                                                                   constant:400];
    // width
    [_label addConstraint:constraint];
    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_label
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:_label
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                             multiplier:0.5
                                               constant:0];
    [_label addConstraint:constraint];

    // vertical
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_label, self.view);
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-100-[_label]-68-|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:views];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    // horizontal
    constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_label
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:self.view
                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                             multiplier:1
                                               constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the 'Taking Control of Auto Layout in Xcode 5' video from the [WWDC 2013 Videos](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) -- Quickly: the top part of the Add New Constraints area is probably what your looking for

[image: Add New Constraints]

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the response!  Although, I don't see how the top part of the constraints UI will help me.  If I set the constraints surrounding the entire UIButton, it will simply squash the button vertically going from 4" to 3.5" retina display...  What I really want is somehow to constrain the aspect ratio while keeping the distance of top and bottom constraints the same...  is there a way to do this?

Comment: What you _could_ do is create two IBOutlets for the constraints and multiply those accordingly. You can create IBOutlets for NSLayoutConstraints just like anything else: [Here's an example](https://copy.com/Sa3j6yKvvTI1On6V).

Answer (score 0):

I guess preserving aspect ratio is NOT possible in auto layouts via interface builder.  #fail.

According to this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50319/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2, at the very end of the tutorial.

So, i guess I need to do this programmatically somehow.